# What happens when I try to run a constexpr function inside a non constexpr function?

Tags: c++, constexpr, compile-time

Title may be misleading, not sure how to explain this but I'll provide an example.

So I have this structures:

```
struct mom {
public:
    static constexpr auto create(int i) {
        return a(i);
    }

    struct a {
        int* m_a;

        constexpr a(int i) : m_a(&i) {
            change();
        }

        constexpr void change(void) {
            *m_a += 100;
        }

        struct b {
        public:
            static int get(a* import) {
                int* arr = new int[10];
                arr[1] = *import->m_a;

                return arr[1];
            }
        };
    };
};
```

And I call it like this:

```
printf("%d", mom::a::b::get(&(mom::create(10))));
```

It is supposed to add 100 the 10 (or any other value you give it) at compile time, then at runtime to store it into a dynamic array and return it to you.

This code is almost exact to my project, but it has a problem: instead of adding 100 to the value, it returns a random big number (-95321314). I tried debugging it and it is all fine until I call the get() function in which I have no idea what is happening that causes this

any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, Clang gives me a [nice warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8dUQz7).

Comment: @chris you are right, looking to fix it right now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `m_a` is a pointer to a temporary, as soon the stack unwinds further usage of that temporary is undefined.

Specifically, the call to `mom::create(10)` returns a struct `a`, whose member `m_a` is no longer pointing to a valid region of memory. Subsequent usage of that member will be undefined (e.g. the copy into `b`'s array in `get()`)

---

A simple "fix" would be to change `m_a(&i)` -> `m_a(new int(i))`, although note that this introduces a memory leak and changes the memory layout entirely. Since it's not clear to me what your design goals are, it's a reasonable alternative to get things "working".

Comment: You are most likely right. I am trying to find a way to move the get() function inside struct a and see if it works. it is pretty hard since I want it all to be in 1 line and I cannot make it static

Comment: Yes @Bozz,  i've added a "fix" although without more information on your design goals it's hard to know if this is helpful

Comment: the constructor is a constexpr constructor, since I want to do this in compile-time, as I said. Are you sure this would work?

Comment: added another external structure that holds m_a and put that instead of the m_a and it works now somehow. hopefully it lasts cause i have 0 idea why it works